# Avoid sql injection in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

How to filter query parameters before inserting them into table to prevent sql injection?

Have such code:

```
$QueryParams = Yii::$app->request->getQueryParams();
$model = new Accounts();
$model->attributes = $QueryParams;
$connection->createCommand()->insert('accounts', $model->attributes)->execute();
```

Is this safe approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The approach is safe, but there is a better one:

```
$model = new Accounts();

if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->get()) && $model->save()) {
    // 'when the model is saved' logic here
}

// other code
```

This basically does, what the posted code does, but includes model validation, is shorter, and is easier to understand.

Comment: PHP and HTML tags have nothing to do with SQL injections.  I fail to see something wrong with this answer.  On the contrary, it's the default, save, and idiomatic way to do inserts in Yii2 and should be encouraged.  HTML tags escaping should be handled elsewhere (in views, to avoid XSS attacks).

Comment: In addition, the above code will run validation for you. +1

Comment: You are correct, but there is no need to filter the users' input here.  SQL injections are prevented by Yii's ActiveRecord implementation, which is exactly what was asked for.  HTML escaping or sanitizing is a completely different animal unrelated to the issue at hand.

Comment: what to use when working with 3rd party Databases which are not part of our model ?

Answer (score 2):

The approach is safe. But, if the `Accounts` class is an `ActiveRecord` class (extends it), then you can simplify your code:

```
$model->load(Yii::$app->request->get());
$model->save();
```

It's equivalent to:

```
$connection->createCommand()->insert('accounts', $model->attributes)->execute();
```

Which is less intuitive, and may even have compatibility problems if you are using a different kind of database.

Also, sometimes you need raw queries. In this case it's preferred to use **prepared statements**:

```
$result = $connection
    ->createCommand('SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE name=:name')
    ->bindValues([':name' => $name])
    ->queryColumn();
```

There is a good [Yii2 security best practices](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/security-best-practices.md) guide on GitHub.